# Custom <blockquote> HTML markup

Tags: functions, customization

In Wordpress, I would like to add a custom styling to the `<blockquote>` elements, replacing Wordpress' default usage by using a function (or however is easiest).

When using the WYSIWYG editor, highlighting text, and then clicking the "blockquote" button, I would like the highlighted text to be wrapped with the following HTML rather than just a `<blockquote>` tag:

```
<div class="span3 quote well"> 
  <i class="icon-quote-left icon-2x pull-left icon-muted"></i>
  <blockquote class="lead">HIGHLIGHTED TEXT</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a shortcode for that? This way you can leave the functionality as is, still have your individual markup, and bundled as a plugin, you can easily _take it with you_ to another WP install, for example.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_shortcode('my_blockquote', 'my_blockquote');
function my_blockquote($atts, $content) {
    return '<div class="span3 quote well">'.PHP_EOL
        .'<i class="icon-quote-left icon-2x pull-left icon-muted"></i>'.PHP_EOL
        .'<blockquote class="lead">'.$content.'</blockquote>'.PHP_EOL
        .'</div>';
}
```

Then, on a page/post, just write:

> [my_blockquote]Content goes here...[/my_blockquote]

and that's it.

---

**// EDIT**: To add a *quicktag* button, put this also in `functions.php`:

```
function add_blockquote_quicktag() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    QTags.addButton( 'my_blockquote', 'B', '[my_blockquote]', '[/my_blockquote]', 'B', 'My blockquote', 1 );
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'add_blockquote_quicktag' );
```

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate this into a function so that it is automatically applied even in the WYSIWYG editor, so the user only has to highlight and click rather than remember the shortcode? (I know - laziness - but the user is "slow").

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: Why not use $content = null ?